# Retrieve segment from value

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I have this value in my field which have 5 segment for example `100-200-300-400-500`.

How do I query to only retrieve the first 3 segment? Which mean the query result will display as `100-200-300`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: For this kind of question, what are the keyword(s)? Yea I tried to think of solution but no result.

Comment: @4LeaveCover, this is a typical question about `substr`. Anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` will be faster and less CPU intensive as compared to `REGEXP`.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '100-200-300-400-500' str FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT substr(str, 1, instr(str, '-', 1, 3)-1) str
  5  FROM DATA
  6  /

STR
-----------
100-200-300

SQL>
```

The above `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` query uses the logic to find the `3rd` occurrence of the `hyphen` "-" and then take the substring from `position 1` till the third occurrence of `'-'`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran explain plan on both your statement above and `REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '^[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+')` and got the same result. I also tried `REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '^([^-]+-){2}[^-]+')` and again, same result. I did the same on a table with many rows -- same result in explain plan.

Comment: Explain plan might not reveal the truth. Generate tkprof and examine. Time elapsed and CPU cost will be more for regexp

Answer (score 1):

```
((\d)+-(\d)+-(\d)+)
```

If the Position of this sequence is arbitrary,  you might go for **REG**ular**EXP**ressions

```
select regexp_substr(
                      'Test-Me 100-200-300-400-500 AGain-Home',
                      '((\d)+-(\d)+-(\d)+)'
                    ) As Result
from dual

RESULT
-----------
100-200-300
```

Otherwise Simple `SUBSTR` will do

Answer (score -1):

you have tow way, the first is substring.

The second is fast, us a REGEXP like this.

```
 REGEXP_SUBSTR('100-200-300-400-500','[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{3}')"REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: The value in my segment do not have a fixed characters. I cannot just put 3 digit there.

Comment: @deniskohl, can you prove the second approach of `regexp` is faster? I bet it will be slower than `substr`. Also, your query would not give desired output if the number of digits vary in each numbers since you have hardcoded `3`.

Comment: I think this might be the regex you're looking for: `REGEXP_SUBSTR('100-200-300-400-500', '^([^-]+-){2}[^-]+')`